# File Uploading in iOS Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios

I’ve been trying to upload a PDF file from the file system.
Worked good in iOS Simulator whereas not in iOS Devices.
‘UIFileSharingEnabled’ is set ’True’ in info.plist.
Below’s the Code…is there anything that I am missing?

==================

```
        var docPicker = new UIDocumentPickerViewController(allowedUTIs, UIDocumentPickerMode.Open);
        docPicker.DidPickDocumentAtUrls += (object sender, UIDocumentPickedAtUrlsEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var filename = Path.Combine(e.Urls[0].LastPathComponent);
            string msg1 = string.Format("Successfully imported file '{0}'", filename);
            string msg2  = string.Format("Failed to import file '{0}'", filename);

            NSData data = NSData.FromUrl(e.Urls[0]);

            if (data != null)
            {
                byte[] dataBytes = new byte[data.Length];
                ViewModel.PDFBytes = dataBytes;
                Console.WriteLine(data + "Completed");

                var alertController = UIAlertController.Create("import", msg1, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                var okButton = UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (obj) =>
                {
                    alertController.DismissViewController(true, null);
                });
                alertController.AddAction(okButton);
                PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);
            }
            else
            {
                var alertController = UIAlertController.Create("import", msg2, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                var okButton = UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (obj) =>
                {
                    alertController.DismissViewController(true, null);
                });
                alertController.AddAction(okButton);
                PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);
            }
        };
        PresentViewController(docPicker, true, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your first line:

```
var docPicker = new UIDocumentPickerViewController(allowedUTIs, UIDocumentPickerMode.Open);
```

to:

```
var docPicker = new UIDocumentPickerViewController(allowedUTIs, UIDocumentPickerMode.Import);
```

Check this link for info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uidocumentpickermode?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12